# Can you move the location of azure-pipelines.yaml to another Azure Repository?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

he is my scenario =>
I had an azure repos A containing 3 folders A1 A2 A3, in each folder i had a CI file and a CD file.
I wanted to split my repo and reconfigure my pipeline to point to the new repos and keep the some path.

changing the path in the some repos is possible but I was wondering if it's possible to reconfigure an existing pipeline to use a yaml file from another repos ?

Screenshot:
[image]
here I can chose another file but not another file from another repos

Thank you in advance = )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found whre you can do it
Edit your pipeline, and it's in the Triggers tab
[image: triggers location]

Then go to yaml tab => get sources  => Repository

Comment: done (I had to wait 48 to accept my own answer ^^), thank you @LeoLiu-MSFT and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use templates as described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).

E.g. you have a YAML Repository called "YAML" containing the file build.yaml and you have the Repository called "UsingYAML" which needs the build.yaml file.

To access the build.yaml in YAML-Repo do the following:

```
name: 'Pipeline_using_a_template'

steps:
- template: build.yml@YAML # Template reference for build
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
I will edit my question with some screen shots to explain more.
in my case i'm trying to "link" my pipeline to a new file in another repos

Comment: Ok, got it. I've had the same problem about a year ago. The only solution was as descriped in my Anwser. So in your case you have to create the cd-pipline.yml in the "shared" repo with all the logic inside. And a cd-pipline.yml containing only the template step in each repository which needs the logic from the shared repo.

Edit 1: Just saw your anwser. So the problem was that you want a Pipline to be startet after another pipeline has finished?

Comment: oh my problem was to move a yaml file containing the pipeline logic to another repository, but the UI in the settings tab allow me to only change the path in the some repository, so my question was about referencing my pipelines file from another repository = )

Comment: Ok, yeah so as far as i know, you need the two files with one referencing the moved file.